# win32com error - Internal error - the buffer length is not the sequence length encountered using dataframe.torecords()

Tags: python, pandas, win32com

I am using the below code to copy my existing dataframe to an excel worksheet using the win32com.client . below is the code

```
    import win32com.client as win32,sys
    import pandas as pd
    excel_application = win32.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    excel_application.Visible = True
    lta_df = pd.read_excel("C:/Temp/temp_lta.xlsx",sheetname=0,
                                    header=0,na_filter=False)
    lta_df["Updated"] = pd.to_datetime(lta_df["Updated"])
    workbook = excel_application.Workbooks.Open("C:/Temp/temp_lta.xlsx")
    ws= workbook.Sheets.Add(After=workbook.Sheets(workbook.Sheets.count))
    start_row= 1
    start_col = 5
    lta_df= lta_df.reset_index()

    ws.Range(ws.Cells(start_row,start_col),
     ws.Cells(start_row+len(lta_df.index)-1,start_col+len(lta_df.columns))
     ).Value =  lta_df.to_records(index=False)
```

I get the below error when I use to_records()

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<ipython-input-779-91e88023cb75>", line 3, in <module>
        ).Value =  lta_df.to_records(index=False)

      File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 565, in __setattr__
          self._oleobj_.Invoke(entry.dispid, 0, invoke_type, 0, value)

      TypeError: Internal error - the buffer length is not the sequence length!
```

what can be the solution for it. All the values are in str
The same error is encountered when I use

```
      start_row = 1
      start_col = 1
      arr_temp = lta_df.values.copy(order="C")
      ws.Range(ws.Cells(start_row,start_col),
     ws.Cells(start_row+len(lta_df.index)-1,start_col+len(lta_df.columns))
     ).Value = arr_temp
```

Answer (score 1):

The error comes up because win32 doesnt understand your data type (either pd.Dataframe or np.ndarray). The way I do it is

```
# first by converting dataframe to contiguous array 
# this is needed because array has to be C_CONTIGUOUS in order to
# write it using win32com
# you can check whether your array is contiguous by using .flags method
lta_df2 = np.ascontiguousarray(lta_df) 
# second step is to convert the array to list
lta_df3 = lta_df2.tolist()

# now you can write lta_df3 to excel using win32com
start_row = 1
start_col = 1
ws.Range(ws.Cells(start_row,start_col),
 ws.Cells(start_row+len(lta_df.index)-1,start_col+len(lta_df.columns))
 ).Value = lta_df3
```

Also, I recommend you to add python and pandas tags

Also #2, you might want to subtract 1 from `len(lta_df.columns)` like you did for `start_row+len(lta_df.index)-1`